# Compiling Ninject for Xbox360

Tags: compilation, xna, ninject, xbox360

I have read in a few places that you can compile Ninject to work with the Xbox360, however I have downloaded the source and cannot seem to get it to compile. So can anyone divulge how to do so (if it is indeed possible)?

== Edit ==

I have added the current build arguments:

XBOX; XBOX360; NO_WEB; NETCF; NO_LCG; NO_ASSEMBLY_SCANNING; NO_EXCEPTION_SERIALIZATION

Is this acceptable? I am just throwing stuff in to get it compiling, I don't know if it will blow up if I deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to delete this question, but as there is very little information online around this I thought I would leave it up here as it compiled fine and seems to be including. It will be a while before I get around to testing it for sure but until someone comes up with a better answer I would use the build arguments above.